# Microsoft Graph API - Recent documents not refreshing

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api

We are working on the Office365 and Sharepoint integrations application.
The application is about document management, and the Sharepoint groups are the key concept.

One of the main functionalities is to list Recent files for Group and for User as well.
For fetching recent Group files, we are using the query on the Microsoft Graph api: `/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/root/children`
For fetching recent files for User, we are using the query: `/me/drive/recent`

The problem is next: Since the first query, for recent files for Group works fine and returns the updated results immediately, the second query (for fetching User’s recent files) is refreshing very slowly and sometimes we are waiting up to a couple of days to get the latest results.

Does anyone have some advice on how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `/drive/items/root/children` is not the same as `/me/drive/recent`. `/children` returns the entire contents of the folder, not just recent files. `/recent` returns recently changed files from _any_ folder. You can use `/me/drive/root/children` to retrieve the same type of results you're seeing from the Group.

Comment: Same problem here. The endpoint /v1.0/users/xxx/drive/recent does not shows files that I've added/modified a few minutes ago (directly in the user's OneDrive, or in SharePoint site, or team)
However until june (?), the endpoint results were quickly (instantly or in few minutes) updated according to drive changes.
Strangely, using Microsoft Graph Explorer interface, the same endpoint is showing added/modified files instantly.

Comment: I agree with Marc said above. If you still see issue, then i would suggest you to report the issue with Microsoft Support. Apart from MS Graph explorer, you can use POSTMAN tool to see if they show the data correctly or not as well.